# power bi dax last value over a period

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this table below. How to get Revenue_MTD in DAX? Revenue_MTD equals to the revenue of the last month of each year. The tables are from Tableau and I am converting these to power bi.

[image]

with only years:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the revenue of the same month previous year you can add a calculated column with this type of dax expression :

```
Revenue_MTD = SUM(Revenue),
    PARALLELPERIOD(
        [Date],
        -12,
        MONTH)
)
```

you can have more detail on this link :
https://radacad.com/dateadd-vs-parallelperiod-vs-sameperiodlastyear-dax-time-intelligence-question

Comment: Ok what do you want exactly then ?
 get the currentmonth and calculate the sum over the currentmonth -1 each year ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard powerbi measure, it should be fairly easy for you to implement this.

MEASURE = CLOSINGBALANCEYEAR(,[,][,])
.
.
.
MEASURE = CLOSINGBALANCEYEAR(SUM(Revenue), DATE )

As long as you have a Date column with appropriate Date Column it should work.

then create another measure with only SUM(revenue)

Answer (score -1):

What expression are you using for your [Revenue_MTD]? Are you using the built-in DAX function TOTALMTD?

Comment: Revenue_MTD equals to the revenue of the last month of each year.